# How to clear mocha.js state in browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, runtime, tdd, mocha.js

I assign tests for mocha.js at runtime in browser.

How to clean or clear mocha.js state and test state added with `describe()`, `it()` and `mocha.run()` methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mocha.suite.suites = [];` resets all suites. I removed previous HTML DOM output manually.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `mocha.suite.suites = [];`
I've found that you also need to set `mocha.suite._bail = false;`

Without this, mocha will abort subsequent test runs on the first failed assertion.